# Defining puppet class ordering when if statement exists

Tags: puppet

I have a Puppet class which, among other things, sets up a whole bunch of Debian repositories, performs an apt-get update and then installs a few packages.

The ordering must be strictly as follows:

1. setup apt sources
2. apt-get update
3. install application packages

To define the ordering, I have used the following chaining after declaring all of my resources:

```
File['/etc/apt/apt.conf','/etc/apt/sources.list'] ->
Exec['apt-get update'] ->
Class['vim','sudo', ..., ..., ]
```

However, here is the issue:

If I set vim to install only if the host is a virtual machine, and the host I am performing the Puppet run on is physical, the run will fail. I assume this is because it is attempting to run Class['vim'] as per my chaining but cannot find the class declaration due to the contents of the if statement not being parsed.

Here is the code:

```
if $::is_virtual == 'true' {
    class {'vim': 
      set_default => true,
  }
}
```

I can work around this by adding a "requires => Exec['apt-get update']" to my vim resource declaration and removing from my chain, but this feels a bit hacky. Here is what my class declaration looks like once I do this:

```
if $::is_virtual == 'true' {
    class {'vim':
      requires => Exec['apt-get update'],
      set_default => true,
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any other methods of dealing with such ordering issues? Is there anyway I can deal with ordering classes held within conditional statements which may or may not be triggered via chaining? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Writing dependency chains like this is hacky exactly because of issues like the one you're dealing with now. It's much safer to handle dependencies by require/notify/subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using `require` is sound. If you **really** have to stick to the chaining operator, you can wrap the `if` block in yet another class.

```
class site::vim {
    if $::is_virtual == 'true' { ... }
}
```

Then include and chain `Class[site::vim]`, which will honor the `is_virtual` value on its own.